# Raw HTTP client not returning any data

Tags: python, sockets, http

```
import socket

host = 'www.google.com'
port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


try :
    client.connect((host, port))
except socket.error:
    print ("Err")

package = '00101'

package.encode('utf-8')


client.sendall(package.encode(encoding = 'utf-8'))

response = client.recv(4096)


print (response.decode('UTF-8')
```

I kept getting `b''` as my return, so I'm trying to decode it. The error I receive is `unexpected EOF` while parsing. Should I not include the `decoding()` function in my printing? I've tried printing only response, the `.decode()` function did not decode. What should I try?

Comment: It looks like you have a `SyntaxError` due to an unclosed parenthesis on the last line...

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a valid HTTP request. For example:

```
package = b'''GET /HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com

'''

client.sendall(package)
```

Which correctly returns a redirect on my machine. Note the empty line at the end of `package`, which ends the request.

When you send `b'00101'` and start reading, the google server has not yet processed your request and returns nothing. By sending a trailing newline (`package = b'00101\n'`) it will start processing your request, and you will get:

```
...
<p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, didn't realize that specific string was that vital.